# How Can I Find Public Datasets related to graduation rates from public high schools?

Tags: data-request

I am looking for data, preferably large public datasets, related to graduation rates from public high schools according to zip code across American states. Can you help me with them?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to OpenData SE. Could you please rephrase your question title with the body?